# Read in delimited file to list

Tags: coldfusion

I want to read in a list of information from a specified url that will eventually be put into a database.  I want to use a 2d array to simulate the rows and columns of the database.  How would I accomplish this with cold fusion?

example file:

```
blah|stuff|123123
wurd|noise|123121
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of options depending on the application. Some examples are:

1) Treat the content as a series of lists, with rows delimited by new lines and columns by a "|". Then [loop](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/Tags_j-l_10.html#3301338) through the lists and append the data to an array or insert it into a database.

```
...
<cfset rows = []>
<cfloop list="#content#" delimiters="#chr(13)##chr(10)#" index="data">
    <cfset arrayAppend(rows, listToArray(data, "|", true))>
</cfloop>
```

2) Another option is [cfhttp](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/Tags_g-h_09.html), which can convert *well formed* files directly into a query object. It has some limitations, but works in many cases.

```
<cfhttp url="http://www.somesite.com/pageThatGeneratesFile.cfm"
     firstRowAsHeaders="false"  
     delimiter="|"
     name="queryResult" />
```

3) Most databases provide tools for importing text files. For example MS SQL provides [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

```
BULK INSERT TableName
FROM 'c:\yourFile.txt'
WITH 
(
     FIELDTERMINATOR ='|',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As logical (4) for Leigh's answer: load data in MySQL.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:\youfile.txt'
INTO TABLE TableName
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(col1, col2, col3)
```

More options in [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).